# How to show diff of changes made in a merge commit?

Tags: git

I didn't realize I was in the middle of a merge when I wrote a bunch of code. Now `git log -p` will not show me the diff of this change (which got auto-committed as a merge commit).

How can I get it to show up in my log diff history?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bit disappointing that Git doesn't show you a patch for merges with `-p`.  Part of the reason is that the patch produced by `-p` is a unified diff, and it's created from one base and one target revision.  A merge has two bases, so a unified diff isn't representative of the change that needs to be made.

So there are two ways to get what you want.  `git log -p -c` will show you N diffs in a merge commit, where N is the number of merge parents.  Or, you can use `git log -p --cc` and see a more compacted form of the diff.  It looks a lot like a unified diff, but can handle the fact that merges have multiple parents.  FWIW, `--cc` stands for "compact combined".  Compact combined output is what you would see if you ran `git show SHA1` for the commit in question.

One more small note: if there were no edits where made in a merge commit, then you will not see a diff in the `git log -p --cc` output.  Also, there's current no way to make a diff show up merge commits by default.  You're best bet is to use an alias if you need something short and memorable.

Comment: More accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: Sounds like I can append a `-c` or `-cc` to my `glp` alias.

Comment: It's `--cc` (note the two dashes), but that sounds like a good option for you. :-)

Comment: Sweet. I'm just gonna change my alias for `glp` to `git log -p -cc`. My custom external diff, however, will need to be updated to handle this 3-file insanity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset to your merge commit, and redo it, stashing what you want to apply for a later commit.

You can see more at:

- "[How do I rework a git merge commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13495818/6309)"

That involves a `git reset merge_commit_SHA1`, adding only the files which are part of the merge, and stashing the rest.

- "[Change a deep merge](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#change_single_deep_merge)": it describes the case when the merge commit isn't the most recent, which means you need to rebase the other commits done since the merge commit:

  ```
  git rebase -p --onto $(git rev-parse nonce) HEAD^ $maste
  ```