# Git : show history of a single file, including merge commits

Tags: git

TL;DR : is there a way to list all commits that modified a single file, including merge commits ? Knowing that `git log -p --cc {filename}` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174497/how-to-show-diff-of-changes-made-in-a-merge-commit) does not do the trick.

---

In the following scenario :

- master, branch1 and branch2 exists
- commit C1 introduces a change in branch1
- commit M1 merges branch1 into master
- master is merged into branch2, but there are conflicts, and the merger accidentally breaks some of the changes introduced by C1 ; so we end up with a merge commit M2, that creates a broken branch2
- commit M3 merges branch2 into master, thus breaking master

I understand this scenario is bad news (there should have been automated tests to realize branch2 was broken, and M3 should have never happen in the first place, etc... Back to the sad reality of people being people and screwing up sometimes.)

We had a hard time realizing this, because, althought we knew exactly what file caused the error, we did not find a way to list *all* the commits.

Following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174497/how-to-show-diff-of-changes-made-in-a-merge-commit) question, we tried :

```
git log -p --cc {filename}
```

This only prints commits up to C1.

What are we missing ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
git log -m --no-max-parents -p {filename}
```

Comment: It still won't show the merge commits. Maybe it's worth nothing that our repositories are managed by Atlasian "Stash" tools ; so in our case, some of the merge commits are "automatic" and done entirely on the server hosting the repository... could that change anything ?